# Can't do backward search with big N in vim, some plugins override it

Tags: vim

I just found I couldn't do the backward search with `N` anymore, it looks like to be overridden by some other plugins,

[image]

Not sure how that happened, how do I find out which plugin got this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute `:map N`. That should tell you what `N` is mapped to.

Edit: As @ChrisJohnsen points out in a comment to this, `:verbose map N` will actually get you the most recent script that sets the mapping.

Comment: Also, `:verbose map N` will tell you which plugin file created the mapping (in case it was not obvious from the rhs of the mapping).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen *That's* what was I looking for. I'd seen that method before, but couldn't remember it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

A well known OS agnostic solution when conflicts appears to trace this, is to disable all plug-ins one by one and trying to search again with `N`. This is boring, but that will do the job.

Just for information, if you type `?`, that will do it too.